# Tensorflow: While importing it is showing libcublas.so.9.0 (No such file or directory)but I have cuda 9.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have recently installed CUDA-9.2, CuDnn and GPU version of tensorflow on CentOS 7. While importing it is showing

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But As I have previously mentioned I have CUDA 9.2 installed instead of CUDA 9.0. I have libcublas.so.9.2 file in both `usr/local/cuda/lib64` and `usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64`.
Also in my .bashrc file I have added the following lines:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Install CUDA 9.0

Comment: @talonmies Is there any other solution? Like can Install tensorflow to use cuda 9.2?

Comment: not currently.  You could build TF from sources, or look for somebody who has posted a TF wheel on CUDA 9.2.   Good luck with that.  You cannot use CUDA 9.2 as a replacement or substitute for CUDA 9.0, if your TF build was linked against CUDA 9.0

Comment: Struggling with the same issue... wish there were a way to tell TensorFlow what CUDA version to look for.

Comment: You can install tensorflow from the source to make it work with cuda 9.2.

Comment: If there's some reason why CUDA 9.0 can't be easily installed, you could try to symlink libcublas.so.9.0 to point to libcublas.so.9.2.

Comment: did this work? I have same issue, I need to use cuda 9.2, but my tensorflow is looking for libcublas.so.9.0

Comment: According to [tensorflow tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) none of  the `TF` version supports `CUDA 9.2`. Incase to use `9.2`, you can follow [build from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) document. Many other solutions are discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428415/importerror-libcublas-so-9-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file/) thread may also help you. Thanks!