# why i am getting error for "import tensorflow" in ubuntu even after installing everything for running tensorflow in gpu

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, gpu

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 28, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/harsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

Comment: Have you exported CUDA path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in bash.bashrc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428415/importerror-libcublas-so-9-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file)

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 1.13 recently got released and requires now CUDA 10
I installed CUDA according this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu and got the same issue as the tutorial is still for CUDA 9.
It helped me to install previous version of tf 1.12:

```
pip3 install tensorflow==1.12
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.12
```